# Register storage class memory allocation

Tags: c++, c, memory, compilation, embedded

who will decide the memory or cpu register allocation for a register type storage class? Will it be assigned during compilation or during run time?

Comment: BTW, in embedded systems, one rule of thumb is to not use dynamic memory allocations.  Memory allocations can lead to memory fragmentation and recovering fragmented memory is another lengthy topic (especially for event driving systems and timing critical systems).

Comment: Reminder:  there is another area of memory for automatic or global variables.  The compiler knows the amount of memory used.  Your executable may already have this area reserved.  The variables are initialized before `main()` is called.  In embedded systems, many compilers allow you to reserve memory in blocks and specifically allocate (or assign) variables to these blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation during run-time is handled by `new` or the `malloc` family.  The `delete` and `free` functions dispose of the memory.

Register allocations are assigned by the compiler at compile time.  Register usage is part of the executable code.

Comment: Wouldn't the stack be considered run-time memory?

Comment: Yes and no.  You can't allocate from stack *per se*, as the C++ language does not require a stack.  You can specify variables in local scope (that disappear after execution leaves scope).  Variables can be allocated in registers and not on the stack.  Compilers can pass variables to and from functions via registers.  There is no requirement for a stack.

Comment: If a variable is declared as `static`, it will be placed in the same section as global variables.  The global variable area is already preallocated by the compiler, and managed before `main()` is called.

Comment: When *allocation* of memory is discussed, usually this refers to allocating memory from the dynamic memory area. Generally, this is because the memory on the stack (if there is one), is smaller and limited.  Some objects are split, such as `std::vector` and `std::string`.  These contains have their overhead allocated in local variable storage and their data allocated in dynamic memory (a.k.a. heap).